# @FindBy using xpath vs linkText

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, linktext

@FindBy(linkText= "[Enter Country]") WebElement enterCountryMenu1;
@FindBy(xpath="//a[text()='Enter Country']") WebElement enterCountryMenu2;

This is just for my knowledge, why does the script work if I click the link by xpath element but not with linkText element?
Does linkText require anything else?  I make sure I comment out the first element before testing the second one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the first option `linkText` , your text is wrapped in `[   ]` but not when using the XPath. Check the first option without `[` and `]`

Comment: I tried with and without the[] but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xpath is unique web element identifier some element cant be identify id but can be idetify by xpath and also you can have other links with name Enter country

Comment: There's only one element with "Enter Country".  I believe this maybe the case of xapth being unique identifier for some elements.   Thanks